# Am I allowed to use this URL to download tiles from Bing Maps?

Tags: bing-maps

I have this URL: [http://ecn.t1.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/h{0}.jpeg?g=131](http://ecn.t1.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/h%7B0%7D.jpeg?g=131)

I am using it to download Bing Maps tiles. Am I allowed to do this? I am downloading quite a few tiles from it, and I am worried that I might be inconveniencing other users. This is for an ML project for context.

Comment: Please read the terms of use and seek professional legal advice https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/maps/product (we are not lawyers)

Comment: Thank you. I shall check this out.

Comment: Please Answer your own question instead of placing the answer in the Question.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in the terms and conditions, it said that It should be noted that the tile URLs for Bing Maps change regularly and as such directly accessing tiles from a hardcoded URL is not allowed. Oops. I will modify my code accordingly. However, it seems that so long as I dynamically generate the URL instead of hard-coding it, I should be fine.